# Storing a matrix where every second element is 0

Tags: c++, matrix

I have to store matrices where the non-zero elements are arranged in a "chess table"-like pattern (1,1), (1,3), (2,2), (2,4), etc. I can't store the zero elements, but I also need to implement addition and multiplication.
The elements are stored in this vector:
`std::vector<std::vector<int>> _v;`
And I have
`size_t n,m`
for their size, so printing and addition are fairly straightforward.
Where I run into problems is multiplication.
As an example, multiplying [ [1,0,3],[0,2,0] ] and [ [2,0],[0,1], [1,0] ] would result in [ [5,0],[0,2] ]. The way I'm storing the first matrix is [ [1],[2],[3] ] and the second [ [2,1], [1] ]. Is storing these matrices this way fundamentally wrong? If so, what would be a proper way to store these so I can multiply them?

Comment: Usually cascaded nested `std::vector<std::vector<T>>` are considered to be inefficient for the representations of mathematical matrices, because they generate an unnecessary overhead in correct strorage maintenance (which is the main purpose of the `std::vector<T>`). It's common consensus, that such are better stored in contigous arrays of `int` or `double` values, and partition these in groups of 2, 3, 4 dimensions, which need an algorithm to turn x and y into an index pointing to the underlying data.

Comment: For your very particular case a data structure like `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` seems to be more appropriate. Or even better define a class `Point{x,y}` with correct overloads for all the mathematical / geometrical operations. You'll need the zeroes to do that correctly btw., you can't simply ignore them.

Comment: Some internal representation might be easier than other for your operation. You can still have conversion function to transform your "chessMatrix" into actual Matrix for computation, and another conversion at the end.

Comment: I would say checker-game like and not chess (with chess we play on all cases).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would strongly recommend:

- Storing data in a simple one-dimensional valarray or vector of
  integers. The size of the vector would be "width * height / 2", since
  you won't store every second element.
- Implementing your own get/set methods for accessing items. In these methods, you'll perform the transformation from x, y to index. And you'll get or set the value
  only if x * y is an even number, because you know that every second
  item would be zero. Example:

```
    class CheckeredMatrix 
    {
        // ...
        public:
        void set(int x, int y, int value)
        {
            int i = y * _width + x;
            if (i % 2 == 0)
                _data[i / 2] = value;
        }
    }
```

- Implementing operations add(), sub(), mul() using
  only these get/set methods. Then you don't need to modify algorithms
  in any way. Since you know that every second item is zero, you can
  then optimize the algorithms by skipping every second step, but it
  will work without it.
- Wrapping everything in a class.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to represent your matrix as 2 matrices, one with `(2*i+1, 2*j+1)` coordinates, the other with `(2*i, 2*j)`.
So

```
a 0 b 0 c
0 d 0 e 0
f 0 g 0 h
```

->

```
a b c
f g h
```

and

```
d e
```

Those 2 matrices allow some regular matrix operations (sum, multiplication, transposition).

Comment: Nice. I thought about storing those as diagonals, but this seems more practical.